# how to create dynamic form in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a formtype, ContactoType, this form contain the next fields:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre','text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'contacto.nombre'
                )
            ))
            ->add('departamento', 'entity', array(
                'label' => "Departamentos",
                'class' => 'ProductosBundle:Departamento',
                'property' => 'nombre'
            ))
            ->add('fechaEvento', 'birthday',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                    'class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('promocion','text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'contacto.promocion'
                )
            ))
            ->add('apodo','text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'contacto.apodo'
                )
            ))
            ->add('file','file', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'contacto.fichero'
                )
            ))
            ;
    }
```

The Departamento entity has a field named "requiresadditional" if this is true, and promotion nickname will be displayed, if false they are hidden.
Do not know how you could get the field value "requiresadditional"...

As it should do this?Thank!

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test your Departamento entity in a FormEvent. Read the documentation about FormEvents  [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#event-listeners).

Answer (score 0):

Usually i add all the field to my symfony form and I display / hide the field by using simple javascript event.

Comment: Yes, but I need to show / hide in function of "requiresadditional" value of the Departamento entity to be selected in the Contacto form

Comment: You can add attribute to your options field inside your EntityType by using the following example from the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr